# ERROR actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java

> constructor Student in class javaapplication 14.Student cannot be
>   applied to given types; required:
>   java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,double found:
>   java.lang.String,double reason: actual and formal argument lists
>   differ in length

This is the line that gives me error

```
super(idNum, gpa);
```

here is my code:

```
package javaapplication14;

public class JavaApplication14     
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Person bob = new Person("Coach Bob", 27, "M");
        System.out.println(bob);

        Student lynne = new Student("Lynne Brooke", 16, "F", "HS95129", 3.5);
        System.out.println(lynne);
        Teacher mrJava = new Teacher("Duke Java",34,"M","Computer Science",50000);  
        System.out.println(mrJava);        
     }
}

class Person
{
    protected String myName ;           
    protected int myAge;             
    protected String myGender;    

    public Person(String name, int age, String gender)
    {
        myName = name; 
        myAge = age ; 
        myGender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return myName + ", age: " + myAge + ", gender: " +myGender;   
    }


    //These are the set methods
    void setName(String name)
    {
        myName = name;       
    }

    void setAge(int age)
    {
        myAge = age ;       
    }

    void setGender(String gender)
    {
        myGender = gender;       
    }

    //These are the get methods
    String myName()
    {
        return myName;     
    }

    int myAge()
    {
        return myAge;     
    }

    String myGender()
    {
        return myGender;     
    }
}


class Student extends Person
{
    protected String myIdNum;    
    protected double myGPA;

    public Student(String name, int age, String gender,String idNum, double gpa)              
    {
        super(name, age, gender);
        myIdNum = idNum;
        myGPA = gpa; 
    }

    //These are the set methods
    void setmyIdNum(String idNum)
    {
        myIdNum = idNum; 
    }

    void setmyGPA(double gpa)
    {
        myGPA = gpa;  
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + ", student id: " + myIdNum + ", gpa: " + myGPA;
    }

    public String myIdNum()
    {
        return myIdNum;
    }

    double myGPA()
    {
        return myGPA;
    }
}


class Teacher extends Person
{
    public double mySalary;
    public String mysubjectName;   

    public Teacher( String name, int age, String gender, String 
subjectName,double salary )
    {
        super(name, age, gender); 
        mysubjectName = subjectName;
        mySalary = salary;  
    }

    //These are the setter methods
    void setsubjectname(String subjectName)
    {
        mysubjectName = subjectName;
    }

    void setsalary(double Salary)
    {
        mySalary = Salary;    
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + ", subject name: " + mysubjectName + ", Salary: "  
+ mySalary;
    }

    //These are the getter methods
    public String getsubjectname(String subjectName)
    {
        return subjectName;
    }
    double getsalary(double Salary)
    {
        return Salary ;
    } 

class CollegeStudent extends Student
{
    public String myMajor;    
    public int myYear;

    public CollegeStudent(String name, int age,String gender, 
    String idNum, double gpa, int year, String major )       
    {
        super(idNum, gpa);
        myMajor = major;
        myYear = year; 
    }


    void setmajor(String Major)
    {
        myMajor = Major;
    }

    void setyear(int Year)
    {
        myYear = Year;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + ", major: " + myMajor + ", Year: " + myYear;
    }

    //These are the getter methods
    public String getmajor(String myMajor)
    {
        return myMajor;
    }
    public int getyear(int myYear)
    {
        return myYear ;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is not js. In Java you must put exact number of exact (or implementing) types as defined in one of method signatures

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've posted over 200 lines of code with no indentation - your question would be easier to read and more generally helpful to future visitors if you would isolate this down to a *minimal* example, and then post that in a pleasantly-indented fashion.

Comment: it clearly states, that there is no such constructor, the only constructor available in `Student` class is `Student(String name, int age, String gender,String idNum, double gpa)`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such constructor with two parameters in Student class

Answer (score 0):

Your super class `Student` has following constructor with 5 parameter

```
public Student(String name, int age, String gender,String idNum, double gpa)
```

But, at `CollegeStudent` constructor, `super(idNum, gpa);` expect a constructor with two parameter  `Student(String idNum, double gpa)`,  which is missing in superclass. So, define a constructor at `Student` class like:

```
 class Student extends Person {
   public Student(String idNum, double gpa){

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `Student` and also the class `Person` has no `constuctor` with the `signature (String, double).`

So you have to create this constructor in one of the superclasses or you have to call an other constructor.